# Can I navigate to a background worker's DoWork() method from where .RunWorkerAsync() is invoked?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio it's convenient to press F12 (or right-click and select from the context menu) when looking at a method call to jump to its declaration.

Is there a shortcut, trick or plug-in that makes it possible to easily jump to the method that is subscribed to a BackgroundWorker's `DoWork` event handler?